# How can I copy style of an existing Line2D object to a plot() call? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-2.x

I need to extract style information of a `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` object to use it in a `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` call. And (if possible) I want to make it in a more elegant way than filtering style-related properties from `Line2D.properties()` output.

The code may be like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def someFunction(a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
    line = plt.plot(a, b, marker='x', **kwargs)[0]
    plt.plot(c, d, marker='o', **kwargs) # the line I need to change
```

In the case I want to have both lines plotted with the same styles (including colour), but with different marker.
Also, I want to be able to use 'autocolouring' feature of the `plot()` function unless colour has been given explicitly as keyword argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Line2D` object that is returned by `plt.plot()` has an `update_from()` method, which copies all attributes from the original instance to the new one, but leaves the data of the line alone. You could use this line to copy all attributes and afterwards set all attributes that should differ 'by hand'. Here a little example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D


def someFunction(a, b, c, d, *args, **kwargs):
    line1, = plt.plot(a, b, marker='x', *args, **kwargs)
    line2, = plt.plot(c, d) # the line I need to change

    ##copy properties from line1
    line2.update_from(line1)

    ##set every that should differ *after* update_from()
    line2.set_marker('o')


x1 = np.linspace(0,np.pi,10)
x2 = np.linspace(np.pi,2*np.pi,10) 
y1 = -np.sin(x1)**2
y2 = np.sin(x2)**2

someFunction(x1,y1,x2,y2, '--', lw=3, ms=10, color='g')

plt.show()
```

This gives the following picture:

[image: result of the above code]

If you leave out the `color` keyword, autocolouring will be used.