# Update Line2D properties from line on different axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, copy

In matplotlib, the `update_from` method of a `Line2D` object can be used to copy properties from another line (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54688412/13094868)). This is not working if the two lines live on different axes. The following code:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
line1, = ax1.plot(range(10), "r.")
line2, = ax2.plot(*line1.get_xydata().T)
line2.update_from(line1)
```

raises

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extents'
```

while the traceback leaves me puzzled.

My questions are:

- Why is this error raised?
- How can I copy (all) `Line2D` properties of `line1` to `line2` instead?

**EDIT**

After a bit more testing I can say that the `AttributeError` above is for example raised in a Jupyter notebook session with the `%matplotlib inline` backend. With the `%matplotlib notebook` backend or in a regular Python script (e.g. with the "qt5agg" backend), the code passes without an error but line2 is "invisible" afterwards.

[image]

For completeness, the above image was created using (Anaconda) Python 3.7.9 and matplotlib 3.3.1 with:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mpl.use("qt5agg")

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
line1, = ax1.plot(range(10), "r.")
line2, = ax2.plot(*line1.get_xydata().T)
line2.update_from(line1)

plt.savefig("test.png")
```

The problem remains that I cannot copy the `Line2D` properties from `line1` to `line2`.

**EDIT 2**

Throwing a `plt.tight_layout()` into the mix brings back the `AttributeError`.

**EDIT 3**

As requested in the comments, here is the traceback for the error I get with `plt.tight_layout()` (**EDIT 2**):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    plt.tight_layout()
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 451, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1490, in tight_layout
    gcf().tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2615, in tight_layout
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 308, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 84, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    bb += [ax.get_tightbbox(renderer, for_layout_only=True)]
  File "/home/janjoswig/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.7.12/envs/md379/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 4199, in get_tightbbox
    if np.all(clip_extent.extents == axbbox.extents):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extents'
```

Comment: Could not reproduce your error.

Comment: Maybe you mean this? `ax2.update_from(ax1)`

Comment: You should always post the complete Traceback.

Comment: @Woodford I really mean (Line2D.update_from)[https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.update_from]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `update_from` updates too much, including the transformation and the clipbox. Maybe the error comes from the object being totally invisible after clipping to the wrong clipbox?

A workaround can be to save both before updating and setting them back:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
line1, = ax1.plot(range(10), "r.")
line2, = ax2.plot(*line1.get_xydata().T)
old_transform = line2.get_transform()
old_clipbox = line2.clipbox
line2.update_from(line1)
line2.set_transform(old_transform)
line2.clipbox = old_clipbox
plt.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
```

[image: using update_from between different axes]